# How to remove text not in tag using lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Now i got xml like following:

```
<div>
<p>the first paragraph</p>
<p>the sencond paragraph</p>
something others...
</div>
```

And i want remove these *something others...* from object `content`.

I know it can be got by using `content.xpath('.//text()[not(ancestor::p)]')`, but it seems be no good method to remove these text directly from object.

---

Update: I tried `//p[last()]/following::*`, it does not works as i want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are stored in the `tail` attribute of the previous sibling tag, so to remove all these "something others..." do:

```
for elem in document.iter():
    elem.tail = ''
```

**edit**:

To remove the tail texts of every last `p` sibling in the document:

```
for elem in document.iter():
    if elem.tag == 'p' and not elem.getnext():
        elem.tail = ''
```

Comment: thank you. But your code will remove all tail text... i only want to remove the one after last `<p>`. Any idea?